# Website copyright- Should I use my name or the website's name

Tags: copyright

If possible, I'd like to know whether to use my name or the website's name when making the copyright notice for my website.

I read [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4099/copyright-word-or-symbol) that when I add a copyright notice to my website I should include

> (3) the name of the owner of copyright in the work, or an abbreviation
>   by which the name can be recognized, or a generally known alternative
>   designation of the owner.

Would the use of the website name instead of my name be considered a valid "alternative designation of the owner"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your name, website name or Company Name, either one should be fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use your own name. A website is not an individual or a legal organisation, even though it may be created by, or represent either of those.

Answer (score 1):

Basically by providing the copyright notice, you're telling others that THE content is copyrighted, whether you are the only author or if you get help from a friend and they contribute to your site too (multiple authors).

You don't need to provide your name in the copyright notice, you can only mention your domain or website name if it's unique enough, take a look at nbcnews.com for example.

But a website needs a real valid contact, that's a must if you're serious with what you do.